# How can i connect 2 schema with _id in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a 3 models. ( Collection-Article-Author ) I must connect all to each other with _id in mongodb. But i dont know how can i make it.
For Example :I will have 3 collections. In article must have a field like collectionID and it must be same with belongs to Collection _id. How can i do it ? Thanks for all helps!

Comment: An aggregation query with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) has that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you got an article schema like this:

```
mongoose.model('Article', {
    name: { type: String },
    publishedAt: { type: String },
    authorId: {type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author'}
}
```

In your model define a new field as `authorId` like this:

```
mongoose.model('Article', {
    name: { type: String },
    publishedAt: { type: String },
    authorId: {type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author'} //New field
}
```

And in the code:

```
const article = new Article({
    authorId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(authorId),
    name: 'foo',
    publishedAt: '2021-07-02'
}
```